# Alternate for LAST() function in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In bigquery sql script i have LAST() function where it is using Legacy SQL, ASk is to convert Legacy SQL to standard sql .

when i converted it to standard sql im getting error Function not found:LAST .
What is alternate for last function in standard function?

Answer (score 0):

That should be [`LAST_VALUE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#last_value) which is a window function, so you need to explicitly [define the window](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls#def_window_spec) over which it applies.